# When would you store metadata on a filesystem rather than a database?

Tags: database, metadata

I want to store documents with metadata in a web application such that a person can view them in a hierarchy.

I gather that a typical way to do this is to create a database entry for each document, store metadata in the database and store the files on a filesystem.

It seems much simpler and faster to store both the documents and the metadata on the filesystem. So a directory might look like this

```
$ ls subdirectory
.json
Subsubdirectory
bar.pdf
bar.json
foo.tex
foo.json
```

And then I could get the metadata from the json files (or whatever format I use). I could render subdirectory/foo.html based on the contents of subdirectory/foo.json. And I could render subdirectory.html based on the contents of subdirectory/.json and the contents of the other child json files.

The main disadvantage I've thought of is that it might be harder to search based on the contents of the metadata file (though I could search based on filesystem-level metadata). What other disadvantages are there? And if people do use this approach, why don't I hear about it?

EDIT: I'm not really so concerned about searching; if I build some sort of searching, it'll probably be within a single, smallish directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I could search based on filesystem-level metadata" - you could do this but it means each time you do a search you have to read all the metdata files from the FS and then you have to manually process it. There's no indexing, this is roughly the equivalent of a full table scan in an SQL database (but it's even slower..).

In general storing data on the FS has some other drawbacks, you have to do replication both for durability (so you don't lose files if the disk dies), and if your site is popupar, for scalability. But since you already storing the files on the disk you have to solve this issue anyway.

Comment: Aside from the search capabilities, you seem to be indifferent to the database and filesystem approaches for storing metadata if I'm already using the filesystem for the documents. Is my perception accurate?

Comment: You also have to manage two sets of permissions--one in the database, and one in the filesystem--and keep them more or less synchronized.

Comment: I would definitely use `mongoDB` to store `json`. If you ever have to search or add extra information to all of the nodes, don't store it on FS. If you store huge number of files or if you have big traffic, then, again, don't store it on FS.

Comment: I don't think I'd need to change filesystem permissions. I'd give the web user read-write permissions on the relevant directories, and I'd store the accounts in a database, just as I would if the metadata were in the database.

Comment: I actually wrote this with mongo, using gridfs to store the files, but I felt strange writing the path structure in mongo (although it is an accepted approach https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/PhCktAndbLQ). Perhaps I should stick with that then.